# addEventListener passes on wrong parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

I want to add event listeners to some links in my menu, the parameter i is, in both cases, passed as 2, should be 0 and 1 though. Can't seem to find the problem here.

```
function setMode(m) {
  console.log(m);
  var mode = document.querySelectorAll('.mode');
  document.querySelector('#modus > a').innerHTML = mode[m].innerHTML;
  }


function clickAdd() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#modus div a');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      setMode(i);
    });
  }
}

  <li class="dropdown" id="modus">
    <a href="#">Modus</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" class="mode radio">ExRaid</a>
      <a href="#" class="mode radio">Trigger</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0):

Declare `i` with let in `for` loop to create a block scope for `i`.

`for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {`

```js
function setMode(m) {
  console.log(m);
  var mode = document.querySelectorAll('.mode');
  document.querySelector('#modus > a').innerHTML = mode[m].innerHTML;
  }


function clickAdd() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#modus div a');
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      setMode(i);
    });
  }
}

clickAdd();
```

```html
<li class="dropdown" id="modus">
  <a href="#">Modus</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" class="mode radio" >ExRaid</a>
    <a href="#" class="mode radio" >Trigger</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

**OR:** You can use IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```js
function setMode(m) {
  console.log(m);
  var mode = document.querySelectorAll('.mode');
  document.querySelector('#modus > a').innerHTML = mode[m].innerHTML;
  }


function clickAdd() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#modus div a');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    (function(j) {
     elements[j].addEventListener('click',function() {
          setMode(j);
     });
    })(i);
  }
}

clickAdd();
```

```html
  
<li class="dropdown" id="modus">
  <a href="#">Modus</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" class="mode radio" >ExRaid</a>
    <a href="#" class="mode radio" >Trigger</a>
  </div>
</li>
```